# ext error with zend framework mvc

Tags: zend-framework, extjs

I am trying to setup ext javascript grid within zend framework mvc. I included ext css and js using the following code.

```
$this->headScript()
     ->appendFile('/Resource/scripts/ext/jquery-1.4.2.js')
     ->appendFile('/Resource/scripts/ext/jquery/ext-jquery-adapter.js')
     ->appendFile('/Resource/scripts/ext/jquery/ext-all.js');

$this->headLink()
     ->appendStylesheet('/Layouts/admin/css/content.css')
     ->appendStylesheet('/Layouts/admin/css/ui.css')
     ->appendStylesheet('/Layouts/admin/css/button.css')
     ->appendStylesheet('/Layouts/admin/css/moon.css')
     ->appendStylesheet('/Resource/scripts/ext/css/ext-all.css');
```

when I run the code, I get the following error message from firefox.

syntax error
[Break on this error] \n

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that doesn't really mean much.  I would start by heading over to the Net tab in Firefox and making sure that all of your scripts and resources are actually loading as expected.  If you have any bad paths they'll show up there. (are you sure that `ext-all.js` is really under your *jquery* folder?)

If everything there is OK, put a breakpoint in the entry point to whatever code you're running and go from there.  Without seeing any of your code, it's impossible to help you debug.

Comment: ah..I found it. ext-all.js was not in the directory...what a sily mistake!